# Python *apropos* command

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for all the functions that have a parameter called *adjustable*.

One of these function is **matplotlib.pyplot.figure ().add_axes**. help(matplotlib.pyplot.figure ().add_axes) describes that parameter, that can be present in *kwargs* dictionary.

I tried pydoc.apropos

```
from pydoc import apropos

In [8]: apropos ('adjustable')
No handlers could be found for logger "OpenGL.Tk"

In [9]:
```

This is all what it returned apropos(key).

One brute force way to find what I am looking for is to grep the source code of python from /usr/share/. But I need to do it from the current python environment (only what is present loaded in evaluator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed you're using IPython, if so, there's an extension called [grasp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grasp/0.3.2) which implements its own version of apropos that may be useful here.

The documentation even uses `matplotlib` in its  example.

Comment: I am using either. In this moment emacs is configured to run ipython, but it does not matter which one. For me it is important to find the information that I need. I will test grasp. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[`apropos`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/465cb5ce5a7e/Lib/pydoc.py#l2047) only searches the one-line summaries of all modules, not each docstring of each single function, as that wouldn't be feasable (already importing every single module as `apropos` does and searching it's docstring is quite some overhead).

And even if it would, in the case of [`add_axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) it wouldn't find anything because your search term isn't part of the one-line description.

I'm affraid if you need such functionality, you'd need to implement it yourself.

Comment: I think you are right. I think that etags can do it, but did not try it yet. I need to scan only the functions from pylab  , as it is the only loaded module, and etags can recognize not only python, but any regular language, in this case the doctrings are regular language.

Comment: I think it might be worse than that, as there is a lot of doc-string linking (which get post-processed and re-assembled by sphinx) and a lot of `**kwarg` magic used in the library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quickly written function that walks all current packages in the specified path, using `ast` to find matching parameters, and returning `(filename, funcname, line_no)` for each match.

```
import ast
import pkgutil
import os.path

class FindParameter(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.found = []

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        for arg in node.args.args:
            if getattr(arg, 'id', None) == self.parameter:
                self.found.append(node)

def apropos(parameter, path=None):
    paramFinder = FindParameter(parameter)
    for importer, modname, is_package in pkgutil.iter_modules(path=path):
        try:
            loader = importer.find_module(modname)
            loader.get_code()
            if loader.source:
                tree = ast.parse(loader.source, filename=loader.filename)
                paramFinder.visit(tree)
        except SyntaxError:
            pass # avoid any broken code in the current path
    return [ (loader.filename, found.name, found.lineno) for found in paramFinder.found ]

all_selfs = apropos('self')
```

Comment: I am impressed :). This is close of what I need. However, can you test it a little using `apropos ('adjustable')` after you have imported all pylab? `from pylab import *`. I tested it, and it returns nothing. As a test, please check if it returns `matplotlib.pyplot.figure ().add_axes`.